# Hibernate. QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped even though it is

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I have read through a bunch of posts on this exception but nothing seems to be working. I am querying the Entity name and not the table name. My User model is mapped and it is in my hibernate.cfg.xml. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

model:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", columnDefinition = "serial primary key")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
```

XML:

```
<mapping class="com.project1.models.User"/>
```

DAO impl:

```
 Session session = null;
        User user = null;
        try{
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            String hql = "from User where username = :u";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setString("u", username);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by changing my hql to:
"from com.project1.models.User as u where u.username = :u"

not sure why it needs that but whatever, it works!